# How to execute code when connection finishes in Apache HttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, apache, http

I'm using an Apache's HttpRequestHandler to serve data to HTTP clients. I'm generating content (probably a costly process) for clients, on demand.

I want to take care of two cases:

- normal consumption, it ends, I want to close resources
- client closes connection prematurely, I don't want to keep processing things

I'm using an InputStream (and an InputStreamEntity) that does the process, but I'd like to know if the client closes the resource prematurely (or not) and take actions at the end in both cases.

I've realized that `InputStreamEntity.writeTo` (which is the method used to send the content to the client) doesn't close the input stream I've declared.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by subclassing `InputStreamEntity` and making `writeTo` call close after original behaviour:

```
public class ClosingInputStreamEntity extends InputStreamEntity {
  @Override
  public void writeTo(OutputStream os) {
    try {
      super.writeTo(OutputStream os);
    } finally {
      // close resources
    }
  }
}
```